# simplest way to search substring in Teradata

Tags: substring, teradata

I want to modify a table like this:

```
ID       List            FLG1   FLG2 

1     000, 111, 123         0      0
2     000, 241, 123         0      0
3     888, 187, 111         0      0
4     424, 000, 123         0      0
5     384, 234, 111         0      0
```

If List contains substring '000', then set FLG1 to 1
If List contains substring '111', then set FLG2 to 1

So after modefication， it should like this:

```
ID     |   List     |     FLG1 |  FLG2 

1     000, 111, 123         1      1
2     000, 241, 123         1      0
3     888, 187, 111         0      1
4     424, 000, 123         1      0
5     384, 234, 111         0      1
```

Please help me.Thank you.

Comment: You haven't shown any effort other than illustrating what you want.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could utilize POSITION, but I would prefer LIKE:

```
CASE WHEN list LIKE '%000%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end
```

Assuming the data is just an example and the items in the list might have different lengths his will result in false positives when there's a list like `888, 180007, 111`, so you might better do

```
CASE WHEN ', ' || list || ',' LIKE '%, 000,%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Again, this might fail if the space after the comma is missing.